# content listing of beautifulsoup4 stripped_strings generator

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, generator

I want to obtain a list of tags in a corporate web

link: https://www.naturgy.com/Publicacion/Satellite?pagename=GNF/DocsCrono/Acordeon&pageToShow=1&language=es_ES&cid=1477656850978&mosaico=null&numElementos=12&c=GNF_AcordeonDocCrono&actionURL=/Publicacion/Satellite?pagename=GNF/DocsCrono/Acordeon&dateStart=&dateEnd=&literales=

When I try to obtain tags in it, this works

```
tags = [''.join(s.stripped_strings) for s in sopa.findAll('div',{'class':'docGrouper__item__description cGrayDark'})]
```

I want to get rid of the last one, so I tried something like this

```
destripastripped = [str(s.stripped_strings) for s in sopa.findAll('div',{'class':'docGrouper__item__description cGrayDark'})]
```

but when I tried to access to content, it returned something like this

```
print(list(destripastripped[:-1]))
```

```
['<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>', '<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f2d74e12a20>']
```

How can I convert the generator into an actual list of strings?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.get_text(strip=True)` instead of `.stripped_strings`. Then `tags[:-1]` will print all string but the last one:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.naturgy.com/Publicacion/Satellite?pagename=GNF/DocsCrono/Acordeon&pageToShow=1&language=es_ES&cid=1477656850978&mosaico=null&numElementos=12&c=GNF_AcordeonDocCrono&actionURL=/Publicacion/Satellite?pagename=GNF/DocsCrono/Acordeon&dateStart=&dateEnd=&literales='
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

tags = [s.get_text(strip=True) for s in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'docGrouper__item__description cGrayDark'})]

print(tags[:-1])
```

Print:

```
['EspañaLa compañía realizó más del 30% de las operaciones de bunkering en España el último ejercicio, suministrando 1.600 toneladas de GNL a buques. De esta forma, reafirma su liderazgo en este sector.', 'España,ClientesEl acuerdo, que se suma a las alianzas anunciadas recientemente por Naturgy con otras compañías como Booking.com y Amazon, se enmarca dentro del compromiso de la energética por facilitar soluciones a sus clientes, ofreciéndoles una propuesta de valor diferencial.', 'España,RSC,PatrociniosNaturgy y el Teatro Real han firmado un acuerdo de colaboración por el cual la compañía energética colaborará con el Plan de Fomento de la Ópera de esta institución, declarado Acontecimiento de Excepcional Interés Público. Este Programa se desarrollará durante tres temporadas artísticas 2020-21, 2021-22 y 2022-23, bajo la denominación «Teatro Real, cerca de ti. Programa de difusión social de la ópera» y refuerza el compromiso de Naturgy con el mundo de la cultura y con el Teatro Real de Madrid, del cual es patrocinador desde el año 2003.', 'Corporación,Económico financieroLa compañía ha concluido la primera parte de su Plan Estratégico 2018-2022 y anuncia para el último trimestre la celebración de un Capital Markets Day donde explicará su siguiente fase de transformación, profundizará en la estrategia industrial para la creación de valor en cada uno de sus negocios y actualizará así sus objetivos, reafirmando sus compromisos con el dividendo, con la creación de valor sostenible en todos los grupos de interés y ESG.', 'España,Renovables,Generación,Medio Ambiente y sostenibilidadLas cinco plantas solares fotovoltaicas construidas por Naturgy, en su primer gran proyecto fotovoltaico en España y que empezaron a operar en 2019, registran una producción media anual de unos 480 Gigavatios hora (GWh) de energía, lo que equivale al consumo eléctrico de más de 128.000 viviendas, casi el 22% del total de la comunidad autónoma.', 'España,Renovables,Generación,Medio Ambiente y sostenibilidadEl Parque Eólico El Tesorillo, construido por Naturgy y situado en el término municipal de San Martín del Tesorillo, en la comarca gaditana del Campo de Gibraltar, cumple seis meses desde su puesta en marcha. Durante este periodo, esta infraestructura ha producido 32 Gigavatios hora (GWh) de energía, lo que equivale al consumo anual de más de 12.500 hogares.', 'España,PatrociniosNaturgy es, desde hoy y una vez más, patrocinador oficial del “Año Santo Xacobeo 2021” tras firmar esta mañana un acuerdo de patrocinio para acciones de promoción, apoyo y difusión de esta celebración, considerado de excepcional interés público. El conselleiro de Cultura y Turismo de la Xunta de Galicia, Román Rodríguez, y el delegado de la compañía en Galicia, Julio Gonzalo, firmaron hoy el acuerdo en la Ciudad de la Cultura en Santiago de Compostela.', 'España,Clientes,Negocio electricidadNaturgy suministrará la energía eléctrica a las instalaciones de la Autoridad Portuaria de Alicante durante los próximos 12 meses, prorrogables por 6 meses más. La multinacional energética presentó la mejor oferta técnico-económica de la licitación que le sirvió para ser la adjudicataria del concurso.', 'Fundación Naturgy,Eficiencia energética,Medio Ambiente y sostenibilidad,RenovablesEl director y socio senior de Boston Consulting Group (BCG) y responsable global de los sectores de generación, renovables y utilities, Christophe Brognaux, y la especialista en política económica y fundadora de la consultora QED Economics, Eva Valle, participaron hoy en la cuarta edición del ciclo de conferencias Energy Prospectives, organizados por Fundación Naturgy y el IESE Business School, que inauguró el presidente de Naturgy, Francisco Reynés.', 'Fundación Naturgy,Renovables,GeneraciónUn informe elaborado por PwC sostiene que, ante la creciente entrada de energías renovables, es necesario tramitar con celeridad mecanismos transitorios que contribuyan a garantizar la sostenibilidad del sistema y la seguridad de suministro.', 'España,Clientes,Negocio electricidadEl acuerdo se enmarca dentro del proceso de transformación de Naturgy para adaptar su negocio hacia un modelo más sostenible impulsando la electrificación y el uso de energías limpias para mejorar la calidad del aire y combatir el cambio climático.']
```

Comment: what I wanted was the tag elements marked inside the javascript element. You gave me the hint for the solution: using a separator between texts (`pretags = [''.join(s.get_text('çç', strip=True)) `) and then look for the last one using `rfind` and clipping the string from beginning to the last separator

Answer (score 0):

list(generator) usually works :)

```
[list(item) for item in destripastripped]
```